# SQL Server: Query not linked server providing credencials. Is possible?

Tags: sql-server-2005, linked-server, openrowset, openquery

I tried to query another specific server many times, but i failed... I searched and i found out that the server must be linked with the other server in order to achieve what i want. Unfortunately is not in my hands to change that so my question is, if it is possible to query the other server by providing credentials.
The server i want to query has SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 4 (9.00.5000) and the server i'm working on has SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3(9.00.4035).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OPENROWSET or OPENDATASOURCE instead.  Both allow you to pass credentials.  This is your best option if you are unable to use a linked server.

This example works if you are using SQL Server logins.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'SERVER=<servername>;UID=<username>;PWD=<password>',
   'SELECT FOO FROM FOO.BAR') AS a
```

Comment: Ok but, can you provide an example please?